# Does NPM install latest SEMVER or last published by default?

Tags: npm, npm-install, artifactory, yarnpkg, semantic-versioning

When someone installs an npm package `npm install some-package —save` does it install the latest semantic version or the last published?

I have a private Artifactory registry that I’m trying to have mimic npm as close as possible. We had to re-publish some packages that are now somewhat out of order due to the default install being last published which is not necessarily the latest semantic version.

Answer (score 0):

Default is semver strategy.
You can modify it by a system property named: 'artifactory.npm.tag.tagLatestByPublish'

Check if you have it set otherwise.

It defaults to 'false'.

Under your artifactory home directory check the file named 'artifactory.system.properties'.